# Iterate through x (5) items in a python list at a time

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a list in python `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

I'm curious what might be considered the most "pythonic" way to iterate over this list 5 items at a time so the results are:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list slicing inside a list comprehension:

```
s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
new_s = [s[i:i+5] for i in range(len(s)-4)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```